# Implementation of the MvxBindableCollectionViewSource

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm new to Mvvmcross framework and currently exploring the iOS part of it (ohh and also new to iOS development to draw a beautiful picture of my current situation ^^). I'm using the vNext version.

I've found references to implementation of UICollectionViewController (MvxTouchCollectionViewController and MvxBindableCollectionViewSource), but these classes seem to be only a skeleton for a future implementation (abstract class, missing a kind of MvxSimpleBindableCollectionViewSource at least). I haven't found a sample using this feature.
I've also found a blog post from Stuart which lets presume he's working on this part ([Work In Progress - MvvmCross lists sample](http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/work-in-progress-mvvmcross-lists-sample.html)).

Does anybody already play with this part and know about an implementation or usage example?

I've took a look to the 10 first minutes of the xaminar mentioned by Stuart in its article and seems pretty interesting, a good starting point for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the collection view controller in several customer apps, but don't think I've published any open source samples that use it.

In essence, the use of the collectionview is very similar to the use of the tableview and cell - which is shown in detail in: http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/uitableviewcell-using-xib-editor.html

In vNext, a sample controller might look like:

```
public class MyCollectionView : BaseCollectionView<MyCollectionViewModel>
{
    private bool _needToCallViewDidLoadManually;

    public HubView (MvxShowViewModelRequest request)
        : base(request, new UICollectionViewFlowLayout (){
            ItemSize= new System.Drawing.SizeF (100, 100),
            MinimumInteritemSpacing = 20.0f,
            SectionInset = new UIEdgeInsets (10,50,20,50),
            ScrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Vertical,

        })
    {
        if (_needToCallViewDidLoadManually) {
            ViewDidLoad();
        }
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        if (ShowRequest == null) {
            _needToCallViewDidLoadManually = true;
            return;
        }

        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        _needToCallViewDidLoadManually = false;

        var source = new CollectionViewSource(CollectionView);

        this.AddBindings(
            new Dictionary<object, string>()
            {
            { source, "ItemsSource TheItems" }
        });

        CollectionView.Source = source;
        CollectionView.ReloadData();
    }

    public class CollectionViewSource : MvxBindableCollectionViewSource
    {
        public CollectionViewSource (UICollectionView collectionView)
            : base(collectionView, MyViewCell.Identifier)
        {
            collectionView.RegisterNibForCell(UINib.FromName(MyViewCell.Identifier, NSBundle.MainBundle), MyViewCell.Identifier);
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you are starting development now, then you might also benefit from considering the v3 branch which is just entering Beta.

Comment: Thanks Stuart, pretty straightforward with your solution. I will take a look on how to customize the View, your link will be really helpful !